# Formatting assembly code to break a statement into multiple lines

Tags: assembly, coding-style, masm, code-cleanup

I work with ASCII bit matrices in assembly x86 which looks like this example:

```
Sign_plus   db  00000000b
        db  00001000b
        db  00001000b
        db  00111110b
        db  00001000b
        db  00001000b
        db  00000000b
        db  00000000b
```

However, I'd like to keep *db [sth]* in new line to make the sign more visible and aesthetic ie.

```
Sign_plus   
        db  00000000b
        db  00001000b
        db  00001000b
        db  00111110b
        db  00001000b
        db  00001000b
        db  00000000b
        db  00000000b
```

But in this format the compiler (MASM/ML) reports an error *A2008*. Is there any way to continue writing a statement in new line or are we forced to type *db/dw/etc.* in the same line where label is?

Comment: Try adding colon after the label. Sign_plus: db  00000000b

Comment: As Shemhamforasch said, colon woked for me in EMU8086, without it I get an error.

Comment: Thank you guys, it works great :) I answered my own questions for other people visiting this with CC for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Shemhamforasch* and *Jose Manuel Abarca Rodríguez* have just said, adding a **colon** solves the problem.

```
Sign_plus:
        db  00000000b
        db  00001000b
        db  00001000b
        db  00111110b
        db  00001000b
        db  00001000b
        db  00000000b
        db  00000000b
```